# Create multiple text files corresponding to its pdf file names from directory in Python

Tags: python, loops, automation, file-conversion, pdftotext

I'm just a beginning trying to practice python with file conversions. Kindly help me out with this.

I am trying to convert .PDF files to .TXT files which i am able to get it work for a single file usung the code below:

```
import pdfplumber

pdfPath = r'C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles\abc.pdf'

txtPath = r'C:\Users\xyz\txtfiles\abc.txt'

with pdfplumber.open(pdfPath) as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        with open( txtPath, encoding='utf-8', mode='a') as f:
            f.write(text)    
print("Operation Success!")
```

Above code is working.
However, i wish to automate the process for all multiple pdf files from my '..\pdffiles' directory and create corresponding text files in the '..\txtfiles' directory with the **SAME NAME** as that of it's PDF counterpart using a loop. Can someone help me with the code to get that done?

Any suggestions are much appreciated !!
Good day !!

Comment: Loop over the files in the directory, capture the file name as a variable, trim the extension using `os.path.splitext()` and store using the new file name.  Essentially, it’s just string manipulation.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import pdfplumber

path_to_your_files = "/path/to/your/pdffiles"
for filename in os.listdir(path_to_your_files):
    
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(path_to_your_files, filename)
    with pdfplumber.open(absolute_file_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            with open(
                    os.path.splitext(absolute_file_path)[0] + ".txt", encoding="utf-8", mode="a"
            ) as f:
                f.write(text)
    print("Operation Success!")
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by filename being a 'relative' path. How would that affect my code or would i need to make any change elsewhere accordingly? Have not worked with os library before. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: relative-path means it will only contain the file names, not the actual path that `pdfplumber.open` might expect. for e.g if you iterate through the path `"C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles\"`  then `filename` will only contain the `abc.pdf` and not `C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles\abc.pdf`.

Comment: if you're having problems using a relative path I can edit my answer to include an absolute path. Let me know.

Comment: This explains the FileNotFoundError i have been facing. Would you suggest i do a os.chdir("/mydir") or create a variable and re-store the 'directory'+path and then pass to the pdfplumber.open ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Applied the changes and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the listdir function from the os library

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Call this function with the path to the folder containing your pdf files (pdffiles). This will return a list of all your pdf files in that folder.

Looping through that list, remove the pdf extension from the file, and use that for the txt file name.

eg.

```
import os

folder_pdf = os.listdir('C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles')
for file in folder_pdf:
    name, ext = file.split('.')
    txt_path = f'C:\Users\xyz\txtfiles\{name}.txt'
    pdf_path = f'C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles\{file}'
    # Code to read pdf and write to text file
```

Comment: I just tried this out but got a FileNotFoundError:  Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.pdf'. File "C:\Users\xyz\sampletryautomate.py", line 9, in <module>
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:

Comment: You need add the path to the pdf file name. `pdf_path = f'C:\Users\xyz\pdffiles\{file}'`

Comment: Got it. Works like a charm now. Thanks a lot